# Can Toshiba H200 sshd be my only Hard drive

Tags: desktop-computer

Am I able to use H200 as my only hard drive in my PC? It's the only one I have and it's my first gaming PC I've built.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. It should be no different from any other HDD/SSD (except performance).

Comment: @SamVessey If this thread answers your question, you should click on the grey checkmark to its left to make it green. Doing so adds a little bit of reputation score to you too.